# Return function name in python?

Tags: python, function

Doing a math function of the type `def`.

```
def integral_error(integral,f):
    ------stufff-------
    print integral
```

gives something like: `'<function simpsons at 0xb7370a74>'`

is there a way to get just simpsons without string manipulations? ie just the function name?

Comment: Well you got a bunch of answers quickly, probably because of a catchy title, but you really could have given a better description of the problem and what exactly you're looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

```
integral.func_name
```

Or:

```
integral.__name__
```

Though, they are exactly equivalent. According to [docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html):

> `__name__` is Another way of spelling func_name

Here's a sample code:

```
>>> def f():
    pass

>>> f.__name__
'f'
>>> f.func_name
'f'
>>>
```

Comment: You might want to add that according to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html), `func_name` and `__name__` are completely equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by using `integral_error.__name__`.

Comment: the OP wanted to have the name of `integral`, i think

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__name__` like so `integral.__name__`